# c++ string table .res file

Tags: c++, string

I use eclipse and mingw32.
I created a STRINGTABLE in an .rc file:

```
STRINGTABLE
BEGIN
    IDS_HELLO,   "Hello"
    IDS_GOODBYE, "Goodbye"
END
```

and compiled to a .res file

I would like to use this STRINGTABLE in an application.
Maybe I should create a dll file? or what?

here is my main application where I would like to use:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>

int main () {
        // text.LoadString(IDS_HELLO) ; somewhere here...
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: So write a function that loads the string and returns a std::string (or std::wstring) as the result?

Answer (score 1):

See [the reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa380599%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). You have to:

1. Adjust linker options so that the compiled .res will be included in your .exe output (no, a dll isn't mandatory);
2. Use the [`LoadResource`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms648046%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) WinAPI function to get a handle to the resource.

Comment: I would like to create a mult-language option in my appication, based on this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/goglobal/bb688160.aspx
So I think i need to create a .dll file.